# can't run springboot applicaltion by Cannot instantiate ApplicationContextInitializer:ServerPortInfoApplicationContextInitializer

Tags: spring-boot

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer : org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServerPortInfoApplicationContextInitializer
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServerPortInfoApplicationContextInitializer

Comment: Welcome to SO, please include the following https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Please add the pom.xml and what you have tried till now.